# How to introduce fees into the returns of a mutual fund?

Tags: fama-french, mutual-fund

In the paper by Fama & French (2010) *Luck versus Skill in the Cross-Section of Mutual Fund Returns*, from J. of Finance ([link](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/bespeneckbo/default/AFA611-Eckbo%20web%20site/AFA611-S8C-FamaFrench-LuckvSkill-JF10.pdf))

the following table is given (Table II, page 1920):

[image]

But they do not explain how to get it the net alpha exactly with the formula. So, I was wondering if the formula contains fee then I can get the net alpha. Or how do I get it by what formula? all I have is the fee and the value of the commission:

```
Daily Commission Value = Closing value of the previous day * {[(1+ E.A. Commission Percentage) ^ (1/365)]- 1}
```

But I get stuck when I try to enter it in the regression:

```
Rp-Rf = (Rm-Rf) + SMB + HML + e
```

Finally, what I need to calculate is the net alpha. Thanks you for reading.

Comment: The FF regressions were run with Gross Returns or with Net Returns. The text above the table says "Net Returns are those received by the investors", Gross Returns are net returns plus 1/12th of a fund’s expense ratio for the year". The regression intercept is $a$ (a monthly figure), but the value shown in the table is $12 a$. Does this help?

Comment: Also, the word "commissions" is never mentioned in the FF paper. What commisiions are you referring to in your question above? and where did you get your Daily Commsission Value formula?

Comment: You don't need to calculate the Net Returns, they are the (ordinary) returns given to you by the Mutual Fund Returns database that you are using (Morningstar, Yahoo, or whatever). You need to calculate the Gross Returns, by adding back to the net returns one twelvth of the Yearly Expense Ratio for the fund. Then you run the FF regressions twice, with Net Returns on the left hand  side or with Gross retuns on left hand side.